# local variable 'utilisateurs_serializer' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

`
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def utilisateur_list(request):

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    utilisateurs = Utilisateur.objects.all()
    
    firstname = request.GET.get('firstname', None)
    if firstname is not None:
        utilisateurs = utilisateurs.filter(firstname__icontains=firstname)
    
        utilisateurs_serializer = UtilisateurSerializer(utilisateurs, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(utilisateurs_serializer.data, safe=False)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    utilisateur_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    utilisateur_serializer = UtilisateurSerializer(data=utilisateur_data)
    if utilisateur_serializer.is_valid():
        utilisateur_serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(utilisateur_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 
    return JsonResponse(utilisateur_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`
**Error**
[image]

Comment: Can u add related code of `firstname`, Is that referring to `Django` default `User` model?

Comment: the variable `utilisateurs_serializer` is defined only inside the `if`  block. So when the `if` is not executed, the variable is undeclared.

Answer (score 0):

In the `GET` block, there is an `utilisateurs_serializer` which is not assigned outside of it!

You can return a `404 Not Found` error:

```py
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']) 
def utilisateur_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        firstname = request.GET.get('firstname', None)
        if firstname is not None:
            utilisateurs = Utilisateur.objects.all()
            utilisateurs = utilisateurs.filter(firstname__icontains=firstname)
            utilisateurs_serializer = UtilisateurSerializer(utilisateurs, many=True)
            return JsonResponse(utilisateurs_serializer.data, safe=False)

        return JsonResponse(status=404)

    ...
```